# How to retrieve inserted identity in migration of FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-migrator

During a migration how do i Insert into my table, then retrieve the ID, and then use it to insert a related data in another table.

what i have now is an hardoced ID to insert, but I don't know what it's gonna be when i'll run the migration.

```
var contactId = 2;
var phoneNumber = 2;

Insert.IntoTable("Contacts")
    .WithIdentityInsert()
    .Row(new
    {
        Id = contactId,
        TimeZoneId = contact.TimeZoneId,
        contact.CultureId,
        Type = (byte)(int)contact.Type,
        Email = contact.Email.ToString(),
        EntityId = entityId
    });

 Insert.IntoTable("PhoneNumbers")
    .WithIdentityInsert()
    .Row(new
    {
        Id = phoneNumberId,
        phone.Number,
        Type = (byte)(int)phone.Type,
        ContactId = contactId
    });
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the inserted ID and use it for the second insert instead of harcoding it.

I'm using SQL Server if it's any help...

I Thought this would be trivial, but seems like it's not, after googling for it, and not seing any answers here.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies within the context of `fluent-migrator`, but have you looked at `@@IDENTITY`? (It is a tsql system function.)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @DMason I know how to do it in SQL, what i want to know is how to do it with FluentMigrator. Or how to get @@Identity with a select after the insert with fluentmigrator

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on the FluentMigrator code but after taking a quick look I can't see a way to do this, so it would have to be a new feature. I'm not sure how familiar you are with the code but you could possibly make a change to the https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/blob/master/src/FluentMigrator.Runner/Generators/SqlServer/SqlServerQuoter.cs class, where if you put in @@IDENTITY it doesn't try and treat it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `Execute.Sql()` with `@@IDENTITY` in sql-query for same cases

Comment: Execute.Sql() returns a void, so you won't be able to get the identity out from the executed statement.

Comment: I mean the use of @@IDENTITY into sql-query: Execute.Sql("Insert ... ; Insert ... values(@@IDENTITY, ...)"). If you want use identity in c# code - you may use Dapper for example: int id = connection.Query<int>("Select @@IDENTITY").Single();

Answer (score 5):

You are able to manually insert the Id by chaining `.WithInsertIdentity()` after your `.Row()` call.

This will let you keep it in memory for use within other objects as Foreign Keys. Unfortunately, FluentMigrator doesn't actually execute any SQL until after all code within the `Up()` or `Down()` methods finish executing.

Comment: This method is from the FluentMigrator.Extensions.SqlServer package