# How to get last inserted id in FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, mysql, fluent-migrator, last-insert-id

I'm using FluentMigrator with MySql and C#.

```
[Migration(3)]
public class _0003_TestMigrationTI : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Insert.IntoTable("cmn_file_types").Row(new { Name = "Image", Code = "IMG" });

        ???
    }
}
```

How to get last inserted id after Insert.IntoTable in the **same** Up() method?
The ID is an INT PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT column in cmn_file_types table.

Comment: This may be a duplicate question. Here's what I found searching: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167605/how-to-retrieve-inserted-identity-in-migration-of-fluentmigrator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve inserted identity in migration of FluentMigrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167605/how-to-retrieve-inserted-identity-in-migration-of-fluentmigrator)

Answer (score 0):

MigrationBase class has ConnectionsString property. Just use it creating your ADO.net query:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
var query = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Table')"    

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    var lastId = command.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
}
```

update:

Try this one. Worked for me. Here you'll get the same transaction for your new query, unlike that case with ADO. So "select IDENT_CURRENT" will show you uncommited current Id.

```
Execute.WithConnection((IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction) =>
            {
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.Transaction = transaction;
                command.CommandText = @"select IDENT_CURRENT('TestTable1')";
                var count = command.ExecuteScalar();
            });
```

Comment: I have added these lines after the Insert.IntoTable, but the lastId will be 0. I think it is because the insert is running on other transaction and it will be committed after the Up method.

Comment: yes, you're right. Missed that moment with transactions. Just remembered that we can use Execute.Sql. Maybe it can be helpful in case you'll find how to get value back. Let me check if it's possible